# How to force NetBeans load Gradle project instead of Maven pom?

Tags: maven, netbeans, gradle

We have a project with both build.gradle script and an old maven pom.xml.  Netbeans (8.0) will try to load the project as a maven project because of the existence of the pom.xml.  Is there a way to force it to load the project as a gradle project using build.gradle? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible in NetBeans. The simplest way is to remove/rename pom.xml. Maven support will ignore this folder in such case and it will be recognized.

I filled RFE for this - https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243778

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response.  Hopefully this will be addressed soon in Netbeans.

Comment: Still hasnt been addressed, but renaming the pom to pom.xml_bak worked for me